# System stalls using include files

Tags: memoir, lualatex-dev

With no style file the following MWE works as expected.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside, onecolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{StyleFile}
\begin{document}
   
\include{Chap1}
\include{Chap2}
            
\end{document}
```

Where the Chap1 and Chap2 files are:

```
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\section{Section 1}
"Hello from first section "
\section{Section 2}
"Hello from second section "
```

and

```
\chapter{Chapter 2}

\section{Section 1}
"Hello from first section "

\section{Section 2}
"Hello from second section "

\section{Section 3}
"Hello from third section "
```

But the content of some style files causes the system to hang before entering Chapter 1.  For example

```
\setSingleSpace{\baselinestretch}
\sidebar{\resizebox{!}{}{\thechapter}}
```

where either line by itself at least get into Chap1 but the two together don't,

So what sort of content should be avoided in style files to have the inclusions processed?

P.S. Looks like I stripped this down too much.  The original style file included

```
\makechapterstyle{mypedersen}{%
    \chapterstyle{default}
    \setlength{\beforechapskip}{-20pt}
    \setlength{\afterchapskip}{10pt}
    \setlength{\cftchapternumwidth}{50mm}
    \setlength{\wraptwidth}{3cm}
    \setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\color{HeadingsRed}}% Set \section style.
    \setsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries}% Set \subsection style
    \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont\LARGE\itshape}
    \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\oldstylenums\HUGE\itshape\colorchapnum}
    \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\huge\itshape\colorchaptitle}
    \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
    \setlength{\midchapskip}{20mm}%Was \numberheight
    \renewcommand*{\chapternamenum}{}
    \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
        \sidebar{%
        \hspace*{-48pt}%  <-- added
        \raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][l]{%
        \resizebox{!}{\midchapskip}{\chapnumfont\thechapter}}}}}%   
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\chaptitlefont ##1}}
```

which worked fine until I split the code out into individual chapters. That of course require some colours and widths to be defined first.

Comment: what would you want `\resizebox{!}{}{\thechapter}` to do? it is asking tex to scale the content to an unspecified size

Comment: It's a very stripped down MWE from a redefinition of a pedersen format which worked fine until I split the chapters up into individual files.  I can include that if it help[s.

Comment: `\resizebox{!}{}{\thechapter}`  can never have worked, perhaps it was simply never executed previously

Comment: Thanks for the help David. Pasting the code back in rather than having it in individual files now gives C:/Users/.../epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(C:/Users/.../epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(C:/Users/.../pdflscape/pdflscape-nometadata.sty
(C:/Users/.../graphics/lscape.sty)))

Comment: they are not errors they are the standard tex log of packages loaded so give no information to anyone to help

Comment: you have tagged this lualatex-dev is that the format you are using?

Comment: the new question with the larger `StyleFile.tex` runs without error. The answer posted answers the original question, if you have a new question post an example that shows the error,

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside, onecolumn]{memoir}

\begin{document}
   

\resizebox{!}{}{\thechapter}

\end{document}
```

produces the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \resizebox
              {!}{}{\thechapter}
?
```

As `graphicx` has not been loaded

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside, onecolumn]{memoir}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
   

\resizebox{!}{}{\thechapter}

\end{document}
```

produces the error

```
Runaway definition?
->}\ifx \@tempb \@tempa \ifx \@tempc \@tempa \toks@ {\mbox }\else \toks@ \ETC.
! File ended while scanning definition of \@tempc.
<inserted text> 
                }
<*> aa125
         
?
```

as the mandatory size to scale the text to has not been specified.

As the error caused it to consume the entire file, you then end at the `*` prompt where (in the default interactive mode) tex will wait for you to type more input

```
? 

*
(Please type a command or say `\end')
*\stop
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]</usr/
local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on aa125.pdf (1 page, 9001 bytes).
Transcript written on aa125.log.
```

So the error is unrelated to using a package or `\include` it's simply an error in the tex input.

Comment: Thanks David.  I had commented out graphix in my original.  Restoring it gets me this in log file "Package: lscape 2020/05/28 v3.02 Landscape Pages (DPC)
)
Package pdflscape Info: Auto-detected driver: pdftex on input line 81.
))
Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.

\openout2 = Introduction.aux" sand it sits there.

Comment: If you provide an example of the error (as you did with `\resizebox` then it's easy to debug it,  but if you don't it's not really possible. @DLyons  with `graphicx` commented out surely you must have had an error that `\resizebox` was not defined. After _any_ error stop and fix that, otherwise as shown here tex may fail to recover and fail at some arbitrary later place (end of file in the example here)

Comment: @DLyons if tex "stalls" it is either as shown here waiting for more input or you have an infinite loop `\def\x{\x}\x`  I would guess waiting for input is more likely here, but thatcan happen for _any_ error earlier in the file that has made tex look ahead to find something that is not there. the point at which it runs out of input and waits for more is not interesting, what matters is what caused the earlier error.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback.  I'll dig back through the code and see what else I changed.

Comment: In the end of the day it was a cluster**** of things. Gimp produced a file that LaTeX considered malformed. Miktex saved a definition as a pdf which led to MPS to PDF being called in the background even on jpegs. And finally multiple overfull hboxes seemed to stall it.